# How to check before adding a new random string?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a Database that contains many rows , I want to update a column in each row with a **4 characters** random string `0-9a-zA-Z` , But after making sure that this random string is not already exist.

The important part that all the columns should be updated with unique string , I don't know how this could be done , Maybe by recreating a new random string when the random string already exist.

So that at the end If the Database contains 500,000 rows for example , All the 500,000 rows are updated with a unique random value.

The table is called `messages` and the column is called `messageid`.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

First, why a string?  Why not just use an integer for a message id?  This would be easy to implement:

```
set @m := 0;
update messages
    set message_id = (@m := @m + 1)
    order by rand();
```

You can do something similar with a string, but it is more cumbersome and using a number makes this much less painful.

Comment: Nice +1 please note that this query will cause a error on MySQL servers that have enabled `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` because there isn't a WHERE clause used within this query.

Answer (score 0):

From the question it seems you want to generate a random string.
Basically to achieve this you need to play with rand() function.
You can use this to achieve the random string.

```
select conv(floor(rand() * 9999), 20, 36) ;
select SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 4);
```

To apply to your table,

```
update messages
    set message_id = (select conv(floor(rand() * 9999), 20, 36));
or



update messages
        set message_id = (select SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 4));
```